# Why there is dotted line in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

[image: excel sheet]

The line between D and E is dotted. Why? How can I change it to normal (eg. the line between E and F)?

I am using Excel 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those dotted lines indicates the page break, meaning where a page ends and where another start.

To remove it, go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> Display options for this worksheet, untick `Show page breaks`.

[image: Page break option]